# dynamic foreach into foreach

Tags: php, dynamic, foreach, simple-html-dom

I am trying to read a **random** website's HTML by using **PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser**

For example, I am trying to read a `span` on some website.

`span` position is in `body > div[class=row] > span`

I can use this method for catch the `span` target:

```
foreach ($html->find('body') as $element) {
    foreach ($html->find('div[class=row]') as $element) {
        foreach ($html->find('span') as $element) {

        }
    }
}
```

This code works fine. But what if I want to create a dynamic `span` position?

For exampe, The `span` position was `body > div[class=row] > div[class=con] > span` , How can I make it dynamic in `foreach`?

I have some dynamic input for entrance tags names like `div` or something.
these inputs can be 1 or more, I can send theme by `Form`, but the problem is:

How to make enough `foreach` into the last one? like:

`Foreach > Foreach > ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of arrow(>) you can use space( ),

```
foreach ($html->find('body') as $element) {
    // Find all <span> in <div> which class=row 
    foreach ($html->find('div.row span') as $element) {
         // check span data here
    }
}
```

Comment: i didnt try this one yet . but .. can i use `div[class=row] span` instead of `div.row span` ?

Comment: Yes sure. It must work.! Instead try both! Both should work.